# Nested general update pattern with d3 v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying out D3 v4 and I'm stuck on a trivial problem but I can't put my mind around it nor can I find anything about it.

Basically, I'm having a stacked bar chart, I'm using `d3.stack()` to format my data but I don't know how to update my `<rect>` when my data change.

I based my code on [the stack bar example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) and here is [a simple implementation of how my code is](http://jsbin.com/naqonilahe/edit?js,output) (it works on enter, not update)